# Why the Mobile plugin support code for Edwiser course format not reflecting as output in Moodle app?

Tags: moodle, moodle-mobile

By following the Creating mobile course format plugin development guide, I am developing a mobile plugin support of the Edwiser course format for the Moodle App. But after creating `db/mobile.php`, `classes/output/mobile.php`, `templates/mobile_course.mustache` as instructed in the guide, I am still getting the default course format in the mobile ie. the courseformat when the course format plugin isn't supported. But when I change the course format in the server to something like flexsections it works in my mobile app.

These are my files:
moodle/course/format/remuiformat/db/mobile.php:

```
<?php

$addons = [
    'format_remuiformat' => [
        'handlers' => [ // Different places where the plugin will display content.
            'remuiformat' => [ // Handler unique name (alphanumeric).
                'delegate' => 'CoreCourseFormatDelegate', // Delegate (where to display the link to the plugin)
                'method' => 'mobile_course_view', // Main function in \format_remuiformat\output\mobile.
                'styles' => [
                    'url' => $CFG->wwwroot . '/course/format/remuiformat/mobile.css',
                    'version' => 2019041000
                ],
                'displaysectionselector' => true, // Set to false to disable the default section selector.
                'displayenabledownload' => true, // Set to false to hide the "Enable download" option in the course context menu.
                'init' => 'remuiformat_init'
            ]
    ]
    ]
];
```

moodle/course/format/remuiformat/classes/output/mobile.php:

```
<?php

class mobile {

    /**
     * Main course page.
     *
     * @param array $args Standard mobile web service arguments
     * @return array
     */
    public static function mobile_course_view($args) {
        global $OUTPUT, $CFG;

        $course = get_course($args['courseid']);
        require_login($course);
        $html = $OUTPUT->render_from_template('format_remuiformat/mobile_course', []);

        return [
            'templates' => [
                [
                    'id' => 'main',
                    'html' => $html
                ]
            ],
            'otherdata' => '',
        ];
    }
}
```

moodle/course/format/remuiformat/templates/mobile_course.mustache:

```
{{=<% %>=}}
<core-dynamic-component [component]="allSectionsComponent" [data]="data" class="format-myformat">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let section of sections">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <ion-item-divider color="light">
            <core-format-text [text]="section.name"></core-format-text>
             <!-- Section download. -->
             <div *ngIf="section && downloadEnabled" class="core-button-spinner" float-end>
                <!-- Download button. -->
                <button *ngIf="section.showDownload && !section.isDownloading && !section.isCalculating" (click)="prefetch($event, section)" ion-button icon-only clear color="dark" [attr.aria-label]="'core.download' | translate">
                    <ion-icon name="cloud-download"></ion-icon>
                </button>
                <!-- Refresh button. -->
                <button *ngIf="section.showRefresh && !section.isDownloading && !section.isCalculating" (click)="prefetch($event, section)" ion-button icon-only clear color="dark" [attr.aria-label]="'core.refresh' | translate">
                    <ion-icon name="refresh"></ion-icon>
                </button>
                <!-- Download progress. -->
                <ion-badge class="core-course-download-section-progress" *ngIf="section.isDownloading && section.total > 0 && section.count < section.total">{{section.count}} / {{section.total}}</ion-badge>
                <!-- Spinner (downloading or calculating status). -->
                <ion-spinner *ngIf="(section.isDownloading && section.total > 0) || section.isCalculating"></ion-spinner>
            </div>
        </ion-item-divider>

        <ion-item text-wrap *ngIf="section.summary">
            <core-format-text [text]="section.summary"></core-format-text>
        </ion-item>

        <ng-container *ngFor="let module of section.modules">
            <ng-container *ngIf="module.visibleoncoursepage !== 0">
                <core-course-module text-wrap [module]="module" [courseId]="course.id" [downloadEnabled]="downloadEnabled" (completionChanged)="onCompletionChange($event)">
                </core-course-module>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</core-dynamic-component>
```

I have cleared my mobile app data by App Setting -> Space usage -> Delete all site download data and
I have purged all the caches in my server still no luck.

Could someone please point out where I am wrong or what should I do? I am glad to provide more information required regarding this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To moodle/course/format/remuiformat/classes/output/mobile.php I added:

```
namespace format_remuiformat\output;
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();
```

By following [Development Workflow](https://moodledev.io/general/app/development/plugins-development-guide#development-workflow) of Moodle App Plugins Development Guide. I cleared the mobile app data, logged out and again logged in to my Moodle app, it worked!